# Error stated that the program cannot find symbol for hexa2 and hexa4

Tags: java, substring

I'm a beginner to Java programming. I have the algorithm but I'm having trouble to code it. I would like to compare 2 similar images at position 2 and 4 of RGB hexadecimal pixel values to check whether one of the images has different pixel values than the other one.

My Algorithm logic:

1. `if(image1.substring2 == image2.substring2) && (image1.substring4 == image2.substring4)`, pixels are the same.
2. `if(image1.substring2 != image2.substring2) || (image1.substring4 != image2.substring4)`, pixels are not the same.
3. `if(image1.substring2 != image2.substring2) && (image1.substring4 != image2.substring4)`, pixels are not the same.

I have the remaining codes here. I tried to separate all the process so it is easy for me to troubleshoot later.

//MAIN

```
public class getPixelRGB1
  {
private static int a;
private static int r;
private static int g;
private static int b;
private static final double bitPerColor = 4.0;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream image = null;
    FileInputStream image2 = null;

    getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();

    try {
        BufferedImage img, img2;

        File file = new File("img0.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("imgstega.jpg");
        image = new FileInputStream(file);
        image2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
        img = ImageIO.read(image);
        img2 = ImageIO.read(image2);

        int rowcol;
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width);
        System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height);

        int[][] pixelData = new int[width * height][3];

        System.out.println("Pixel Data: " + pixelData);

        int[] rgb;
        int count = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
            {
                rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++)
                {
                    pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];

                }
                count++;
                System.out.println("\nRGB Counts: " + count);
            }
        }

        int width2 = img2.getWidth();
        int height2 = img2.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width2);
        System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height2);

        int[][] pixelData2 = new int[width2 * height2][3];

        int[] rgb2;
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<width2; i++)
        {
        for(int j=0; j<height2; j++)
        {
        rgb2 = newPD.getPixelData(img2, i, j);

        for(int k = 0; k < rgb2.length; k++)
        {
        pixelData2[counter][k] = rgb2[k];

        }
        counter++;
        System.out.println("\nRGB2 Counts: " + counter);
        }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            image.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}  
}
```

//1ST PROCESS - Get RGB Pixel Values

```
public class getPixelData1 
{
private static final double bitPerColor = 4.0;

public int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int w, int h) throws IOException
{
    int argb = img.getRGB(w, h);
    int rgb[] = new int[]
    {
        (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
        (argb >>  8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb      ) & 0xff  //blue
    };

    int red = rgb[0];
    int green = rgb[1]; //RGB Value in Decimal
    int blue = rgb[2];

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Decimal --> " + "\nRed: " + red + " Green: " + green + " Blue: " + blue);

    //Convert each channel RGB to Hexadecimal value
    String rHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(red));
    String gHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(green));
    String bHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(blue));

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Hexa --> " + "\nRed Green Blue " + rHex + gHex + bHex);

    //Check position 2 and 4 of hexa value for any changes
    String hexa2, hexa4 = "";
    String rgbHexa = rHex + gHex + bHex;

    hexa2 = rgbHexa.substring(1,2);
    System.out.println("\nString RGB Hexa: " + rgbHexa);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 2: " + hexa2);

    String hex = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue);
    hexa4 = hex.substring(3,4);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 4: " + hexa4);

    return rgb;
}
}
```

//2nd Process - to compare the RGB Hex value of both images

```
public class compareHexaRGB
{
public int[] compareHexaRGB(BufferedImage img, BufferedImage img2, int w, int h) throws IOException
{
    getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1(); //get method from class getPixelData1 - is this correct?

            if((img.hexa2.equals(img2.hexa2)) && (img.hexa4.equals(img2.hexa4))) 
              {
                   System.out.println("Pixel values at position 2 and 4 are the same.");
              }
            else if((img.hexa2 != img2.hexa2) || (img.hexa4 != img2.hexa4))
              {
                  System.out.println("Pixel values at position 2 and 4 are not the same.");
              }
            else if((img.hexa2 != img2.hexa2) && (img.hexa4 != img2.hexa4))
              {
                  System.out.println("Pixel values at position 2 and 4 are not the same.");
              }
}
}
```

The error stated that the program cannot find symbol for hexa2 and hexa4 in bufferedImage. Can someone check whether I've done something wrong with my coding here? I'm still new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

`img` is of type `BufferedImage` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)). It does not contain any non-private (nor private) fields named `hexa2` or `hexa4`.

What you need to do is to refactor your code to make sure you have access to them in `compareHexaRGB()`. There are probably many ways this can be done. Perhaps you could extend `BufferedImage` to include your fields, or perhaps you could just pass them as input to the method.

Which solution that would be the more elegant one is hard to determine given that we don't really have all your code (for example, I don't see `compareHexaRGB()` being called at all).

To be more precise about the compilation problem: By using `img.hexa2` to access a field, you assume that there is a field called `hexa2` in `BufferedImage` that is accessible from your class. This is true if a field for example is declared as `public`. More typically, the fields are `private` scoped and need to be accessed by a getter/setter. For `BufferedImage`, no such field exists at all.

Learn about access control [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: how should i do then? i don't really understand the concept. should i create another method to get the bufferedimage value and the hexa2 and hexa4 values? i'm confused

Comment: @user2890264 I am simply explaining to you why you cannot access `hexa2` and `hexa4` in `BufferedImage`. How you should do is a totally different question. You will probably need to think through your code, and post another question when you run into a specific problem.